# Response decoding failed with xmpp sasl authentication

Tags: xmpp

I am trying complete the SASL authentication in XMPP server.

- I have connected to the xmpp server using gen_tcp socket
- I have registered a user 'test4' with password '123'
- Encode the username password using... :base64.encode_to_string('test4')
- Then sent the encoded string i.e dGVzdDQ= to SASL authentication
- Using the command:

:gen_tcp.send(socket, "`<auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>dGVzdDQ=</auth>`")

But the server is giving error      "`<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><bad-protocol/><text xml:lang='en'>Response decoding failed</text></failure>`"

Note: I also tried to send :base64.encode_to_string(' test4 123') to server

Answer (score 1):

As per [RFC 4616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616), you need to put a NUL character before the username and the password.  Try this:

```
iex(1)> :base64.encode_to_string([0] ++ 'test4' ++ [0] ++ '123')
'AHRlc3Q0ADEyMw=='
```